# Prove that $A \mapsto \chi_A$ defines bijection between $\beta(\gamma)$ and set of function ${(0,1)}^{\omega}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was given the following task

> Let $\Omega$ - be some set (finire or infinite)
> Assign to each subset A $\subset\Omega$ function $\chi_A : \Omega \to {(0,1)}$
> Where $\chi_A$ is defined as $\chi_A(x) = 1 $ if $x \in A$ and $\chi_A(x) = 0 $ if $x \notin A$

I need to prove that

> $A \mapsto \chi_A$ defines bijection between $\cal P(\Omega)$ (all the subsets of set $\Omega$) and the set of functions ${(0,1)}^{\omega}$

In this problem, I do not understand the following :

1. What does it mean that some function defines a bijection between set A and set B.
2. What is the set of functions ${(0,1)}^{\omega}$

Comment: What is $\beta(\Omega)$?

Comment: $\beta(\Omega)$ all the subsets of set $\Omega$

Comment: The standard notation for the set of all subsets of $\Omega$ is ${\cal P}(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 0):

There are several notation issues in your question. The right statement of the question should be

> Show that the function $\chi:A \to \chi_A$ defines a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) from ${\cal P}(\Omega)$ to $\{0,1\}^\Omega$.

The set $\{0,1\}^\Omega$ is the set of all functions from $\Omega$ to $\{0,1\}$. In particular, for each subset $A$ of $\Omega$, $\chi_A$ belongs to $\{0,1\}^\Omega$.